# How to solve error "Retrieving package sensors failed to mount" to succeed installation of sensors package by zypper?

Tags: suse, zypper, sensors

I have a server, i need to check server temperature ,so simply i decided to use sensors package, using zypper to install it. So

1. First I used
   `zypper install sensors` command by root user, The result message is
   :
   `Loading repository data... Reading installed packages... Resolving package dependencies... The following NEW package is going to be installed: sensors Overall download size: 84.0 K. After the operation, additional 296.0 K will be used. Continue? [YES/no]: y Retrieving package sensors-3.0.3-3.6.i586 (1/1), 84.0 K (296.0 K unpacked) Failed to mount cd:///?devices=/dev/sr0 on /var/adm/mount/AP_0x00000001: No medium found (mount: No medium found on /dev/sr0) Abort, retry, ignore? [A/r/i]: a Problem occured during or after installation or removal of packages: Installation aborted by user Please see the above error message for a hint.`
2. After that i use `zypper lr -u` command, the result is:

`# | Alias           | Name                  | Enabled | Refresh | URI           --+-----------------+-----------------------+---------+---------+---------------  -------------------------------------------------                                1 | openSUSE 11.1-0 | openSUSE 11.1-0       | Yes     | No      | cd:///?devices =/dev/sr0                                                                        2 | repo-debug      | openSUSE-11.1-Debug   | No      | Yes     | http://downloaddopensuse.org/debug/distribution/11.1/repo/oss/                   3 | repo-non-oss    | openSUSE-11.1-Non-Oss | Yes     | Yes     | http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/11.1/repo/non-oss/        4 | repo-oss        | openSUSE-11.1-Oss     | Yes     | Yes     | http://download.opensuse.org/distribution/11.1/repo/oss/                         5 | repo-source     | openSUSE-11.1-Source  | No      | Yes     | http://download.opensuse.org/source/distribution/11.1/repo/oss/                    6 | repo-update     | openSUSE-11.1-Update  | Yes     | Yes     | http://download.opensuse.org/update/11.1/`

3- By `lsb_release -d` command cleared the my OS description is:

`Description     open SUSE 11.1 (i586)`

Now any body can advise how to solve the error and successfully install Sensors package by zypper?

*** It is necessary to mention that i don't have any installation CD of my server, but i can connect it to internet.

Answer (score 0):

`zypper mr -d 1` will disable the optical disk and that should bypass it and allow installation from the network.

I assume it's trying to get the files from that rather than the network as it's local with no updated file.

However, v11.1 is very old, it's 14 years old and and is no longer supported. It was eol'd 10 years ago. You may struggle to find installation files.

You really need to upgrade.

Comment: 1- First i disable the first repo(that use local devices for URI, cause i don't have any installation devices: disk, sd, dvd, Usb).                                    2- So for `zypper install sensors` it use other enabled repo, but cause the OS version is too old, The URI address are not realy exixst ( as you recommend to upgrade the open SUSE from 11-1 release). But now the matter is that how can i do it? To which release is propper? Automatically or manually? i must be carefull about the other application installed to not be disturbed.

Comment: You cannot upgrade. You will have to install a new version. V15.4 does not support upgrade from any of the V11 versions. Therefore, download the installer disk, backup the present system, install the new version, then recover the backed up data.

Comment: For back up I have some experience with Acronis, full image back up, but here which back up is useful? Can you explain more? How to Create exact disk partition and other subjects?

Comment: Do a file backup.Taking an image backup will not help since you want data files restored, not o/s ones. As to how, I will have to leave that in your hands as a learning experience. And practice backup and restore before taking the plung.

Comment: Acronis has data backup also, but  :                                                                                                              i) How to backup the data backup of installed applications?   Which folders?                                                                                ii) May be the installed application are not compatible with new version of SUSE. I don't have any installation media of them.

Comment: We cannot help you, you are in uncharted waters. We have no idea what you have installed and what is being used or how. What you may be best doing is grabbing another system and gradually move data across, piece by piece.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advises.